# Improving Product import performance

Tags: import

I got an import (which is working fine) for about 40k Products (with variants).
But it takes to long, about 3h for the entire import file.
Does anyone has an idea how to improve the perfomance?

Sync Api was already suggested.

How should I call it when using a console command?

Or are there other idea?

Greets axe

Answer (score 0):

the relevant file is https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/742a536f08355fcaa45a790955253f849e55fc5e/src/Core/Framework/Api/Sync/SyncService.php.

it's there via dependency injection

```
<argument type="service" id="Shopware\Core\Framework\Api\Sync\SyncService"/>
```

(definition here: https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/e496aeb2fd8e21f4cbe4bf6ab6fb5b7d89a43d97/src/Core/Framework/DependencyInjection/data-abstraction-layer.xml)

The implementation is an abstraction of the api call https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/admin-api-guide/sync-api#more-performance

It expects as first parameter an array of SyncOperation, which is as simple as an api post.
As second parameter the context and as third the SyncBehaviour.
The syncbehaviour is really important. There you can say to "disable index" or "use queue indexing".

If you are really sure about your import and you know that you thought of all relevant data what shopware needs you can disable the indexing.

If you are not 100% sure, i would suggest the queue indexing and run "messenger:consume" command afterwards. It will index the relevant data.

Comment: When using "use queue indexing" will the index then run asynchron?

Comment: yeah. But you need to have the "messenger:consume" command either as running service declared, or run it by yourself. See https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/references-internals/core/module/queue#consuming-messages